# SwiftUI Font.Design Picker

Tags: swiftui, enums, picker

Anyone knows a valid way to loop the the 4 enumerated values for SwiftUI's Font.Design in a Picker in order to choose them for the interface ?

The possibilities :

```
case `default`
case monospaced
case rounded
case serif
```

For instance :

```
Picker("Font design", selection: $vm.fontDesign, content: {
    ForEach(Font.Design, id:\.self) { design in
        Text(design.rawValue).tag(design)
    }
})
```

And in the ViewModel :

```
@Published var fontDesign: Font.Design = .rounded
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend `Font.Design` to conform to `caseIterable`:

```
extension Font.Design: CaseIterable {
    public static var allCases: [Font.Design]{
        [.default, .monospaced, .rounded, .serif]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH @Yrb ! 
It works like a charm !

Soon (or late) I'll be there :)

Comment: I literally just had to do a similar one for an app I am working on.

Comment: I was sure that with an extension it was possible, but didn't knew the process. Your post helps understand the how to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The final code will look like this (in order to get the string values for the picker) :

```
extension Font.Design: CaseIterable {
    public static var allCases: [Font.Design] {
        [.default, .monospaced, .rounded, .serif]
    }
    var design: String {
        switch self {
            case .default:
                return "default"
            case .monospaced:
                return "monospaced"
            case .rounded:
                return "rounded"
            case .serif:
                return "serif"
            default:
                return "default"
        }
    }
}
```

View :

```
Picker("fontDesign", selection: $vm.fontDesign, content: {
    ForEach(Font.Design.allCases, id:\.self) { font in
        Text("\(font.design)").tag(font)
    }
})
```